# $\mathbb{C}(V)$ is a finite module over $\mathbb{C}(V)^G$?

Tags: invariant-theory

Is it true that $\mathbb{C}(V)$ is a finite module over $\mathbb{C}(V)^G$ for any finite subgroup $G \subset GL(V)$ and, moreover, $\dim_{\mathbb{C}(V)^G} \mathbb{C}(V) = |G|$? It possibly follows from the well-known theorems of Hilbert and Noether in invariant theory, but doesn't seem obvious to me. Maybe I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There is the following result:

**Prop** Let $V$ be a finite dimensional representation of a finite group $G$ over a field $k$. Then $k(V)$ is galois over $k(V)^G$ with galois group $G$.

The proof is just that $G$ acts as automorphisms on $k(V)$, so we may apply all the standard field theory.

It is immediate from this that your result follows. This result is in Benson's *Polynomial Invariants of Finite Groups* Prop 1.1.1 (i.e., the very first thing anyone proves in the subject :) )